# Is that mysql tables structure ok for historical data?

Tags: mysql

i know there are a lot of similar topics, but in my case my question is more specific.

For the moment I have two tables:

```
date_hours
id | datetime

CREATE TABLE `date_hours` (
  `id` int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `datetime` datetime NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci;

ALTER TABLE `date_hours`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  ADD KEY `date_hours_datetime_index` (`datetime`);

exchange_pair_statistics
id | exchange_id | price | datehour_id

CREATE TABLE `exchange_pair_statistics` (
  `id` int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `exchange_id` int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `exchange_pair_id` int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `volume24h` bigint(20) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `price` double(14,6) NOT NULL,
  `volume_percent` double(5,2) NOT NULL,
  `datehour_id` int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci;

ALTER TABLE `exchange_pair_statistics`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  ADD KEY `exchange_pair_statistics_exchange_id_index` (`exchange_id`),
  ADD KEY `exchange_pair_statistics_exchange_pair_id_index` (`exchange_pair_id`),
  ADD KEY `exchange_pair_statistics_datehour_id_index` (`datehour_id`);

ALTER TABLE `exchange_pair_statistics`
  ADD CONSTRAINT `exchange_pair_statistics_datehour_id_foreign` FOREIGN KEY (`datehour_id`) REFERENCES `date_hours` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE,
  ADD CONSTRAINT `exchange_pair_statistics_exchange_id_foreign` FOREIGN KEY (`exchange_id`) REFERENCES `exchanges` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE,
  ADD CONSTRAINT `exchange_pair_statistics_exchange_pair_id_foreign` FOREIGN KEY (`exchange_pair_id`) REFERENCES `exchange_pairs` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE;
```

In the exchange_pair_statistics table there are more than 20,000,000 records at the moment and every day there are getting more and more.

If i want to find a price for certain date and hour of some exchange, I need first to search in the date_hours table, find the correct that and with that Id to look up into the exchange_pair_statistics table.

I have the indexes on exchange_id and datehour_id, but sometimes I need to make a lot of searches in that big table, so I am wondering is that tables structure the best way for that kind of search ?

Here is the explain table of following example query:

```
select * from `exchange_pair_statistics` where `exchange_pair_id` = 6985 and `exchange_id` = 42 order by `id` desc limit 1

1 | SIMPLE | exchange_pair_statistics | range | exchange_pair_statistics_exchange_id_index,exchang... | exchange_pair_statistics_exchange_pair_id_index | 4 | NULL | 212786 | Using index condition; Using where
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the table structure you have, including the indices, see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query. Also, include a `EXPLAIN SELECT` statement of your `SELECT` statement to see how the query is being executed.

Comment: i have added the tables structure as also the explain table

Answer (score -1):

I think this much of data (20 000 000) is not good for normal table... 
Oracle like Big Data is now Integrating in MySQL. So the best way to store large data in mysql:

MySql have Unlocked New Big Data Insights with MySQL & Hadoop.

1. You can use MySQL as a Document Store. There are possible to store many many object as JSON. It highly recommended and Extendable.

`MySQL Document Store = (MySql + NoSql)`

X Dev API will help to produce JSON with SQL and CRUD operation over X Protocol. Also there is possible to maintain X Session.

It will be best for transparent data sanding and sharing for chat application or group Application.

2. MySql Sysbench: Read Only is another best solution. It will be very fast and scalable to make group chat Application.
3. Use MySql 5.7 : InnoDB, NoSql with Memcached API which will interact directly with storage engine InnoDB. It is 6X faster than MySql 5.6.

Still FaceBook is using this technology because it is very fast. I think you can store your record data.